# How to Pass a String Parameter for a attribute section?

Tags: string, asp.net-core, attributes

I have many actions in a controller (using asp.net core). I am using Route attribute for a routing purpose. Instead of using

```
[Route("case-converter")]
```

on each action, I tried to declare a string and reference that string in this attribute field.

```
string attName="case-converter"
[Route(attName)]
```

But it's not working.The error says it needs a nonstatic field.
How to overcome this? If you have 10 to 15 actions in a controller and all controls need the same attribution how you do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create different parttens and add different constrains to them in the middleware,
I tried as below

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> actiondic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                actiondic.Add("Get", "{controller}/{action}/G");
                actiondic.Add("Post", "{controller}/{action}/Po");
                actiondic.Add("Put", "{controller}/{action}/Pu");
                foreach (var key in actiondic.Keys)
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: key, pattern: actiondic[key], constraints: new { action = key });
                }   
                
            });
```

The controller:

```
//Apicontroller and Route Attribute have been removed
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        ......
        [HttpGet]
        
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            
            ......
        }
        
        [HttpPost]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Post(....)
        {
            .....
        }
    }
```

The Result:

[image]

For More details, you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0)